# Create code from Pattern Graph

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, design-patterns

I got a graph from which I need to set some propery in objects. Im adding an example on which I will explain it better:

[image]

Assuming I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Account { get; set; }
    public string BirthCity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
}
```

Each Person that gets to the DAL will automatically be assigned with Status according to that algorythm. My real problem is much more complex, but this example does explain it well I think.

The graph describes scenarios and I need to translate it to code. I want my solution to be as flexible to changes as possible. Ofcourse writing ifs and switch case is the easiest yet its not a good solution.

One idea I had was creating an Xml file suting the scenarios, but I think that it might not be that good.

Does anyone have any Ideas about this issue?

Comment: Your example doesn't contain any scenarios that I can see. It simply calculates the status of the Person based on some properties. That is pretty static in itself. I assume there are some specifications for the dynamic behavior of the system?

Comment: based on the example above, how would you suggest implementing it?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your graph input: When do you receive it? Only during construction? Can status change during the lifetime of your system for a person? Do you have multiple graphs each one with different logic? What format is the graph given to you or are you supposed to suggest the format to be used? etc. etc.

Comment: I receive it once and its not supposed to be changed dynamically. There is only one graph. meaning, I will get it and just need to create a code that implements it. Status may change but it doesn't concern me because my purpose is only to set an initial value to status according to the graph. The graph only describes what the value of Status needs to be initially. Its just a tool to describe to me as a programmer, whats need to be done. I can implement it as a whole bunch of IFs but then it will neither be cleanly written nor easily changed code.

Comment: I guess you could either write if then else statements and try to keep them as compact and as efficient as possible, or you could try to write a Decision Matrix to handle the logic, but I don't think it would be that simple. One more thought: In the interest of allowing your system to handle status changes of Person objects, you should probably consider implementing it using the State pattern.